# Разобрать отдельные части JSON (немного усложненного)

Tags: java, android, json

Например есть такой JSON http://api.wheelshop.com.ua/app/wheels 
Как его грамотно разобрать по частям, например достать строку "micro"? [image: введите сюда описание изображения],

```
 StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject info = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    System.out.println(info);
                    System.out.println(info.getString("micro"));//не рабочий кусок,для наглядности, что нужно.

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Не рабочая строка** не работает так как поле *"micro"* нету, ты находишься на пару уровней выше в JSON объекте. Вот рабочий пример:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray arr = o.getJSONArray("data");

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject img = arr.getJSONObject(i)
         .getJSONObject("color").getJSONObject("images");

        System.out.println(img.getJSONObject("1").getString("micro"));

    }
```

Но парсить самому это не есть оптимальноe решение, создай модель для этого JSON-а и пускай все это парситься каким то [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Почитай

https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html